# How to connect dishwasher drain hose to drain hose extension

Tags: drain, dishwasher, hose, connectors

We just got a new dishwasher, and I cannot figure out how to connect the drain hose from the dishwasher to the drain hose extension coming out of our floor.

How can I connect the two hoses shown in the attached picture?

[image: drain hoses]

Answer (score 2):

The fitting from the new washer appears to be 1/2" female that would normally attach to the 1/2" barb connection under the sink. The elbow on your extension tube looks like 1/2" too.  You should look for a 1'2" double barb nipple and two hose claps similar to the picture below from Amazon. A PVC double barb nipple would work too with hose clamps

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your response. I just measured the openings for both the fitting for the new dishwasher and the elbow, and they both appear to be about 1 1/16” wide. So would I look for a 1 1/8” nipple? Do they come in that size?

Comment: @user3058361  Go for the 1" bar which will be the inside diameter.The outside diameter will be larger, 1/16" to 1/8".

Answer (score 0):

It appears you need a short piece of solid pipe and 2 clamps.
Possibly 3/4 CPVC.or any size that fits the rubber ends snug.
Then clamp.